# wireshark 2.2.5 - how to set ESP preference from command line

Tags: command-line, wireshark, preferences, tshark

I'm finding a way to set ESP preference, i.e. encryption keys, authentication keys, from command line. I have tried below command but wireshark always says no preference matches mine

> tshark -i - -Y "sip||esp" -d tcp.port=="5000-65535",sip -d
>   udp.port=="5000-65535",sip -T text -l -O "sip,esp" -o
>   esp.enable_null_encryption_decode_heuristic:true -o
>   esp.enable_authentication_check:true -o
>   esp.enable_encryption_decode:true -o "esp.sa_1:IPv4|*|*|*" -o
>   "esp.encryption_algorithm_1:AES-CBC [RFC3602]" -o
>   "esp.encryption_key_1:0xC5DA46E7FF43C8D6C0DD3A2707E42E05" -o
>   "esp.authentication_algorithm_1:HMAC-MD5-96 [RFC2403]" -o
>   "esp.authentication_key_1:0xE5A349FCBAD409D15C766702CD400BA4" >
>   D:\test\dump2.txt

It's always said that "esp.sa_1" flag is unknown. Same as esp.encryption_algorithm_1 and esp.authentication_algorithm_1, and so on.

I have searched around and think that esp.sa_1 is only available in older version of wireshark.

Does anyone know how to have these preference on wireshark 2.2.5?

Thank so much!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the [ESP preferences](https://wiki.wireshark.org/ESP_Preferences) wiki page is out of date.  The ESP preferences have been changed to a UAT (User Access Table), so you can more simply create an *esp_sa* file instead of specifying individual preferences.  Probably the easiest way to learn the format of the file is to create one in Wireshark first, but from the [source code](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-ipsec.c;h=24be677afb209013bf47dda70aa4ab71d04fbb9f;hb=HEAD#l2352), you can see that each entry contains the following information:

- Protocol used
- Source address
- Destination address
- SPI
- Encryption algorithm
- Encryption key
- Authentication algorithm
- Authentication key

For example, an entry might look like:

```
"IPv4","","","","AES-CBC [RFC3602]","0xC5DA46E7FF43C8D6C0DD3A2707E42E05","HMAC-MD5-96 [RFC2403]","0xE5A349FCBAD409D15C766702CD400BA4"
```

But if you really want to specify these options on the command-line rather than creating or modifying the *esp_sa* file, then you can do so.  From section 10.2, [*Start Wireshark from the command line*](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html), of the Wireshark User Guide:

---

*User access tables can be overridden using “uat,” followed by the UAT file name and a valid record for the file:*

```
wireshark -o "uat:user_dlts:\"User 0 (DLT=147)\",\"http\",\"0\",\"\",\"0\",\"\""
```

*The example above would dissect packets with a libpcap data link type 147 as HTTP, just as if you had configured it in the DLT_USER protocol preferences.*

---

So, in your case, you would use something like so:

**Unix**

```
tshark.exe -o 'uat:esp_sa:"IPv4","","","","AES-CBC [RFC3602]","0xC5DA46E7FF43C8D6C0DD3A2707E42E05","HMAC-MD5-96 [RFC2403]","0xE5A349FCBAD409D15C766702CD400BA4"'
```

**Windows**

```
tshark.exe -o "uat:esp_sa:\"IPv4\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"AES-CBC [RFC3602]\",\"0xC5DA46E7FF43C8D6C0DD3A2707E42E05\",\"HMAC-MD5-96 [RFC2403]\",\"0xE5A349FCBAD409D15C766702CD400BA4\""
```

Comment: Hi Christopher. Thanks for leaving answer. I have tried your suggestion but no luck. There's no more error from tshark but seems that the encryption key is not applied. I use the same key, saving as esp_sa file and the result is success. But when using cmd line, no packet is decoded. I'm posting my command in following comment. Please, have a look and correct me if anything goes wrong. I'm capturing from Stdout in which packets are forwarded from an Android device to my Win64 PC. Thanks.

Comment: C:\Users\SEV_USER>adb forward tcp:1122 tcp:1122 && nc 127.0.0.1 1122 | tshark -i - -Y "sip||esp" -d tcp.port=="5000-65535",sip -d udp.port=="5000-65535",sip -T text -l -O "sip,esp" -o esp.enable_null_encryption_decode_heuristic:true -o esp.enable_authentication_check:true -o esp.enable_encryption_decode:true **-o "uat:esp_sa:\"IPv6\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"AES-CBC [RFC3602]\",\"0xAA642911F9A34024A5BFB1B8DDF6FD97\",\"HMAC-MD5-96 [RFC2403]\",\"0x2452952DA20AF3987224A818BD6FC6C8\""** > D:\test\dump2.txt

Comment: should you want to know more what I'm trying to do, please refer to this question [tshark - real-time simultaneously capture & decrypt ESP packets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688602/tshark-realtime-simultaneously-capture-decrypt-esp-packets)

Comment: When it worked using the `esp_sa` file, were you using Wireshark or `tshark`?

Comment: OK, I was wondering if you had used Wireshark and that `tshark` might need to be run with the `-2` option; however, you can't perform a 2-pass analysis when reading from a pipe.  In any case, since you used `tshark` successfully with the `esp_sa` file, then there's something else obviously going wrong with `tshark` attempting to read, process or apply the UAT option, but I don't know what that might be.  Can you post a packet capture file somewhere, perhaps to cloudshark, dropbox, etc?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late response. May I know what you mean "a packet capture file"? A pcap file?

Comment: Basically, yes; however a pcap file is just 1 type of packet capture file.  There are many other file formats, so I used a more general term to describe it.

Comment: BTW, if you still can't get `tshark` to read the command-line `uat:esp_sa` option, I'd recommend that you file a Wireshark bug report for it.  It should work.  See: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for suggestion. I've managed to use esp_sa file instead.